# Slide in CSS react filter bar

Tags: css, reactjs, css-animations

I'm trying to create a slide-in/slide-out animation with no success.
I have a filter bar and it's default mode is close, once the user clicks it, I want it to slides in from the button to the left and when he clicks it again I want it to slide-out into the button. Filter bars + button need to stay in the same line.

Please check my code [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-wind-3kury?file=/filter.js)

Help will be appreciated

Comment: try using CSS animations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need animations for such transitions and simply leverage css transitions. Your sample was almost there, I did a quick update to it solving the behavior & simplifying your filter component

**filter.js**

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./src/styles.css";

export default function Filter() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleFilterClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };
  return (
    <div className="Filter">
      <div className={`toolbar ${open ? "show" : ""}`}>
        <div className="slide-in-content">
          <input type="text" />
          <input type="text" />
          <input type="text" />
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="button">
        <button onClick={handleFilterClick}>
          {!open ? "<< Filters" : ">> Clear"}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**styles.css**

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.Filter {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: blue;
}
.Filter .toolbar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  height: 3rem;
}
.Filter .toolbar .slide-in-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(120%);
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}

.Filter .toolbar.show .slide-in-content {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.Filter .button {
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I managed to get closer to the result [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-wind-3kury?file=/src/styles.css) but it doesn't slide in. And I can't position the inputs inline